# .htaccess RewriteRule without URL change in browser

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somedomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^r/(.*)$ index.php?rid=$1 [NC]
```

But last condition performs redirect in browser when I request URL like `www.somedomain.com/r/123` and show me URL like `www.somedomain.com/index.php?rid=123`. But I need call this script without URL change.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the `R=301` Try to use `L` just like following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain.com [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somedomain.com/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^r/(.*)$ index.php?rid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: `L` = Last Rule
`N` = Next
`QAS` = Append query string
`R[=code]` = Redirect to new url
`NC` = Case insensitive
`NE` = Do not escape output
`G` = Gone ( Not longer exists)
`PT` = pass through
`P` = pass through

And there are more offcourse but i use these most often.

Comment: Ok. Now works, but now absolute path is 2 levels /r/123 and executed script index.php on first level and I have problems with HTML paths to images for example. How can I resolve it?

Comment: set a base path in your html head like `<base href="http://www.somedomain.com">`

And for 2 levels just add another `(.*)` and a `$[0-9`] like following
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ http://www.somedomain.com/$1/$2 [L]`